# How can i update/create a text file with the treeView1 files and directories and read it back later?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp, treeview

I have this method where i'm getting/listing in a treeView1 in real time the directories and files from my ftp server.

```
private int total_dirs;
        private int searched_until_now_dirs;
        private int max_percentage;
        private TreeNode directories_real_time;
        private string SummaryText;

        private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(string path, string name , int recursive_levl )
        {
            var directoryNode = new TreeNode(name);
            var directoryListing = GetDirectoryListing(path);

            var directories = directoryListing.Where(d => d.IsDirectory);
            var files = directoryListing.Where(d => !d.IsDirectory);

            total_dirs += directories.Count<FTPListDetail>();
            searched_until_now_dirs++;

            int percentage;

            foreach (var dir in directories)
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(dir.FullPath, dir.Name, recursive_levl+1));

                if (recursive_levl == 1)
                {
                    TreeNode temp_tn = (TreeNode)directoryNode.Clone();

                    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker( delegate
                    {
                        UpdateList(temp_tn);
                    }));
                }


                percentage = (searched_until_now_dirs * 100) / total_dirs;
                if (percentage > max_percentage)
                {
                    SummaryText = String.Format("Searched dirs {0} / Total dirs {1}", searched_until_now_dirs, total_dirs);
                    max_percentage = percentage;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage, SummaryText);
                }
            }

            percentage = (searched_until_now_dirs * 100) / total_dirs;
            if (percentage > max_percentage)
            {
                SummaryText = String.Format("Searched dirs {0} / Total dirs {1}", searched_until_now_dirs, total_dirs);
                max_percentage = percentage;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage, SummaryText);
            }

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
                numberOfFiles.Add(file.FullPath);
            }           
            return directoryNode;
        }
```

And this is a small method that make the updating:

```
DateTime last_update;

        /// <summary>
        /// Displays the list in real time..
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tn_rt"></param>
        private void UpdateList(TreeNode tn_rt)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - last_update;
            if (ts.TotalMilliseconds > 200)
            {
                last_update = DateTime.Now;
                // clone the list to a new list.. so threads won't bla bla bla
                treeView1.BeginUpdate();
                treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn_rt);
                ExpandToLevel(treeView1.Nodes, 1);
                treeView1.EndUpdate();
            }

        }
```

What i want to do now is to write to a text file in real time the directories and files and next time when i'm running my program again to read it back from the text file so i will not need to get/list all the files and directories from the ftp server since it's taking some time.

I'm not sure if it's good idea i just don't want that the user will have to get/list all the directories and files from the ftp server every time.

How can i create this text file, So when it's updating in real time the treeView1 it will also update/write in real time to a text file and when i'm running the program again it will read the text back and add it to the treeView1 ?

Comment: I think the best way to do that is to use a dataset and save it to XML file when the program is closed or at the end of each updating.

Comment: LPs thanks i found how to do it.